# How to iterate tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

i'm trying to build a data pipelines from tfrecords, here is my code

```
def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {
        'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'image/format': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value='jpeg'),
        'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
        'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
        'image/channels': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
        'image/shape': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/label': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
        'image/object/bbox/difficult': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
        'image/object/bbox/truncated': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    }

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)
    image = tf.io.decode_raw(example['image/encoded'], tf.int32)
    return image
```

Then, i get image after decode

```
    for img in train_ds:
        print(img.numpy())
```

But i got an error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_Dataset_map__parse_image_function_78}} Input to DecodeRaw has length 286478 that is not a multiple of 4, the size of int32
     [[{{node DecodeRaw}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: This isn't a problem with iterating over a dataset but with decoding your tfrecord dataset. Perhaps you could share what is stored with each of the keys? `tf.io.decode_raw` expects raw bytes of the give `dtype` and returns you a 1D tensor with as many of those that it could find.

Comment: `filename = directory + DIRECTORY_IMAGES + name + '.jpg'
image_data = tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile(filename, 'rb').read()`
I read file image and encode to binary file

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the error message is about decoding error, and not a problem with iteration. You are creating the dataset object and iterating through it correctly.

`image = tf.io.decode_raw(example['image/encoded'], tf.int32)` tells TensorFlow to decode the data stored in that key as a tensor of `int32`s. That is, raw binary values of 32-bit integers, for example, the contents of `.data` in a NumPy array with `dtype=np.int32`.

Since you have read in the binary contents of `.jpg` files, I'm assuming that you have binaries of JPEG images at that key value. For this case, you should be using the `decode_jpeg` method instead. You should be using:

`image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(example['image/encoded'])`.

`decode_jpeg` also provides you with some options on how you wish the JPEG data to be decoded (e.g. grayscale only, chroma upsampling method). Full documentation of `decode_jpeg` is available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_jpeg)

Additionally, TensorFlow also provides a `decode_image` that automatically calls the correct supported image format decoder given the binary data. See docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image).

Comment: thanks for your help, but after use `decode_image`, i still got error
`ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'DecodeJpeg' (op: 'DecodeJpeg') with input shapes: [?].`

Comment: Perhaps share how you created the feature? You might have used a rank 1 tensor instead of a scalar. If that's the case you might be able to get away with doing a `tf.reshape(example['image/encoded'], shape=())` or `example['image/encoded'][0]` on the tfrecord file that you have. But ultimately, I'll recommend fixing how the record file was created.